# Erro ao manipular dados JSON de uma API com PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Estou com erro ao manipular dados JSON de uma API, alguns campos eu até consigo manipular. Estou pegando a responsa da API, convertendo para um objeto PHP com a função json decode o problema é que nessa API, o nome do cliente está como "pessoa.nome" e na hora de fazer um foreach para exibir os dados de cada cliente, aparece um erro dizendo que "nome" não foi definido.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.com.br/v1/entidades/HoraTrabalhada?campos=pessoa.nome,totalHoraTrabalhada,valorTotalOriginal,proprietario.nome&page&pageSize=100&criterio",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: ",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {

    $json_obj    = json_decode($response);
    $clientes    = $json_obj->rows;

    foreach ($clientes as $cliente) {
        echo "Valor hora: $cliente->valorTotalOriginal - Cliente: " . $cliente->pessoa.nome . "<br />";
    }

    echo "<br />";
    echo "<a href='index.php'><button>Voltar</button><a>";

}

?>
```

**Erro:**

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$pessoa in C:\xampp\htdocs\apidatajuri\entidades.php on line 33

Warning: Use of undefined constant nome - assumed 'nome' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\apidatajuri\entidades.php on line 33
Valor hora: 0,00 - Cliente: nome

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$pessoa in C:\xampp\htdocs\apidatajuri\entidades.php on line 33

Warning: Use of undefined constant nome - assumed 'nome' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\apidatajuri\entidades.php on line 33
Valor hora: 0,00 - Cliente: nome
```

**JSON recebido:**

```
{"rows":[{"id":101448.0,"pessoa.nome":"Nome da pessoa","pessoaId":"79271","totalHoraTrabalhada":"","valorTotalOriginal":"5,86","proprietario.nome":"Nome da pessoa","proprietarioId":"4204"},{"id":101447.0,"pessoa.nome":"Nome da empresa","pessoaId":"74115","totalHoraTrabalhada":"","valorTotalOriginal":"8,79","proprietario.nome":"Nome da pessoa","proprietarioId":"4204"}],"listSize":51229.0,"modulo":"HoraTrabalhada","pageSize":2.0,"page":0.0}
```

Comment: `$cliente->pessoa.nome`, aqui você está concatenando o valor `$cliente->pessoa` com `nome`. Este segundo, por padrão, será considerado como uma *string* e lançado o *warning* que você obteve, por não ser uma constante definida. Poderia [edit] a pergunta com um trecho do JSON recebido?

Comment: Efetuei a edição exibindo o JSON recebido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao tentar acessar a propriedade pessoa.nome o php vai tentar concatenar o $cliente->pessoa com uma constante de nome "nome". Para resolver o problema coloque o valor dentro de chaves e aspas, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.com.br/v1/entidades/HoraTrabalhada?campos=pessoa.nome,totalHoraTrabalhada,valorTotalOriginal,proprietario.nome&page&pageSize=100&criterio",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: ",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {

    $json_obj    = json_decode($response);
    $clientes    = $json_obj->rows;

    foreach ($clientes as $cliente) {
        echo "Valor hora: $cliente->valorTotalOriginal - Cliente: " . $cliente->{"pessoa.nome"} . "<br />";
    }

    echo "<br />";
    echo "<a href='index.php'><button>Voltar</button><a>";

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado de verdade, fazia 3 dias que eu estava quebrando a cabeça nesse erro

Answer (score 1):

Você fez:

```
$json_obj    = json_decode($response);
```

Se utilizar `print_r($json_obj)` ou utilizar qualquer ferramenta de debug, verá que o valor da variável é:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 101448
                    [pessoa.nome] => Nome...
                    [pessoaId] => 79271
                    [totalHoraTrabalhada] =>
                    [valorTotalOriginal] => 5,86
                    [proprietario.nome] => Nome...
                    [proprietarioId] => 4204
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 101447
                    [pessoa.nome] => Nome...
                    [pessoaId] => 74115
                    [totalHoraTrabalhada] =>
                    [valorTotalOriginal] => 8,79
                    [proprietario.nome] => Nome...
                    [proprietarioId] => 4204
                )

        )

    [listSize] => 51229
    [modulo] => HoraTrabalhada
    [pageSize] => 2
    [page] => 0
)
```

Para acessar a propriedade `pessoa.nome` você não pode fazer `$cliente->pessoa.nome`, pois para o PHP isso será uma operação de concatenação entre os valores `$cliente->pessoa` e `nome`, este segundo estando indefinido será considerado como *string* e será lançado o *warnng* que relatou na pergunta.

Para acessar corretamente esse campo você deve utilizar as chaves, `{}`, em conjunto com uma *string*:

```
$cliente->{"pessoa.nome"}
```

E assim obterá o valor que deseja.

Se você passar `true` como segundo parâmetro de `json_decode`:

```
$json_obj = json_decode($response, true);
```

Você obterá um *array* associativo ao invés de um objeto, então bastaria fazer `$cliente["pessoa.nome"]`, o que simplifica na grande maioria dos casos.